# CCSprite: Batched sprites should use the same texture as the batchnode?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, crash, nodes, ccsprite

I keep getting a crash that says: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'CCSprite: Batched sprites should use the same texture as the batchnode'`

I am not quite sure what this means. I googled the crash but got no results. Also this only happens when I go back to my first scene after coming back from the second scene in my game.

I double checked my code and I make sure all the images in my sprite sheets are added as children to the batch node. I also make sure the images in my app that aren't in my sprite sheet are added as a child to my layer and not the batch node.

Anyway what causes this crash and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

***Edit1***: It seems to be happening on this line in my app:

```
[self.spriteLeft setDisplayFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:imageName]];
```

I NSLog imageName and it returns: MyImage.png , then I look in my plist and pvr.ccz that I load and MyImage.png is **definitely** in there. So I don't know why it is crashing when everything looks right. Also I make sure that I do not use spriteWithFile anywhere where I load an image thats in my sprite sheet.

Comment: Having same issue here.. No solution so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means what it says : when you create the CCSpriteBatchNode object object with a texture, later when you add sprites to the CCSpriteBatchNode, all the sprites you add to the CCSpriteBatchNode MUST be from the same texture. For example:

```
NSString *spriteName = @"agility"; // an example, this code comes from a method that returns the batchNode
                                   // for many status types

NSString *plist = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"status_%@.plist",spriteName];
NSString *textureFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"status_%@.pvr.gz",spriteName];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:plist textureFile:textureFileName];
CCSpriteBatchNode *batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:textureFileName];

//  plist has a frame named status_agility_Ok.png

CCSprite *frameStatusOk = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"status_%@_Ok.png",spriteName]];  
[batchNode addChild:frameStatusOk]; // this will work, both the sprite and the batch node have the same texture

CCSprite *frameStatusNotOk=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"someOtherTextureFile.pvr.gz"];
[batchNode addChild:frameStatusNotOk]; // this will fail an assertion and crash.
```